# Find a function whose derivative matches another function derivative multiplied by a function of derivative indexes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given $g(z)$ an holomorphic function in the whole $\mathbb{C}$. Is there a way to find $f(z)$ such as:

$$f^{(2k)}(z_0) =   g^{(2k)}( z_0 ) \frac{(2k)!}{ (k!)^2}$$

where $f^{(2k)}(z_0)$ denotes the 2kth derivative of $f(z_0)$ for a fixed $z_0$ ?

This question is particularly interesting when $k \to \infty$.

A suboptimal solution could be just finding $f(z)$ such as:

$$ |f^{(2k)}(z_0)| \ge   |g^{(2k)}(z_0)| \frac{(2k)!}{ (k!)^2}, \forall k>1$$

Comment: Question edited to clarify it.

Comment: The second is achievable via $f(z)=g(z_0+2(z-z_0))=g(2z-z_0)$ as $\binom{2k}{k}\le4^k\exp(-\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2(k-1)}-\dots-\frac12)<4^k/\sqrt{k}$.

Comment: I need to dedicate it a bit more of time, and I eventually have some doubts, but looks exactly what I am looking for. I am very happy to flag it as an answer if you want to.

Comment: @LutzL I don't see the reason why you mention $4^k/\sqrt(k)$. I may be missing something but applying your definition of $f(z)$ and deriving we get $f^{(2k)}(z) = g^{(2k)}(2z-z_0) 2^{2k}$ and clearly $2^{2k} \ge    {{2k}\choose{k}}$ what I am missing?

Comment: No, that is exactly right. You get that tighter bound from $\frac{2m-1}{2m}\le e^{-1/2m}$ or by using the Stirling formula, but it is not needed for your purposes. But is shows what gap there is and how likely it is that it can be filled by some nice function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Stirling formula you get 
$$
\binom{2k}{k}=\sqrt{\frac{2k+\theta_{2k}}{2\pi(k+\theta_k)^2}}2^{2n}\simeq\frac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}<4^k,~~ θ_j\in (0,1)
$$
so that a simple re-scaling of the argument will give an example for the inequality case with 
$$
f(z)=g(z_0+2(z−z_0))=g(2z−z_0)\implies |f^{(2k)}(z_0)|=2^{2k}|g^{(2k)}(z_0)|>\binom{2k}{k}|g^{(2k)}(z_0)|.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer really helpful